# regression of a level vs a change variable

Tags: time-series, linear-model, misspecification

This question has likely been asked already but due to the lack of proper terminology I might not have been able to find google up the relevant questions.

We have data for several years: 2000, 2001, ..

As dependent variable we have y, which is a some business forecast (f.ex. sales).
We have a number of regressors. Interestingly, the regressors are not level variables but rather the forecasted YoY change on some macroeconomic drivers ($X_{t} - X_{t-1}$)

We run a very basic regression: $Y \sim  X$. The results seem awesome: statistically significant and 0.9+ R-squared.

I am rusty in this topic. However, I have the suspicion that there's a model misspecification. In particular:

- I fear the exclusion of a "trend" factor and of "time" in this regression
- a scatterplot of $\Delta Y$ vs $X$ does not show any meaningful pattern - and that somehow concerns me

Comment: Should the last bit of paragraph 3 actually say $X_t - X_{t-1}$, or something similar?

Comment: I can't really answer your question but to help point you in the right direction, one of the pieces of terminology that you may be lacking is autoregressive

Comment: No, we do not have an *auto*regressive model, AR as in [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model). We have $Y_t = \Delta X$, where Y and X are not the same quantity. But tnx.